# $n \times n \times n$ cube painted and disassembled, probability randomly chosen small cube rolled has red side acing up?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A large $n \times n \times n$ cube is painted red on all six sides, and then cut into $n^3$ smaller congruent cubes. A cube is selected at random and rolled. What is the probability that it has a red side facing up?

Here's what I got. We have $8$ cubes with $3$ out of $6$ sides painted, $12(n - 2)$ cubes with $2$ out of $6$ sides painted, $6(n - 2)^2$ cubes with $1$ out of $6$ sides painted and $(n - 2)^3$ cubes with no sides painted. So the probability we desire is$${{8\left({1\over2}\right) + 12(n - 2)\left({1\over3}\right) + 6(n - 2)^2\left({1\over6}\right)}\over{n^3}} = {1\over{n}}$$Is this correct?

Comment: Your argument is correct, I didn't check the algebra, it's correct I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct.

Comparing painted small cube faces to total small cube faces (each equally likely to be rolled) $$\dfrac{6n^2}{6n^3}=\dfrac1n$$ is faster but gives the same answer

Comment: I would like to add: the probabilities of each cube showing a red face are all independent. There are $6n^2$ red faces ($n^2$ on each large face) and $6n^3$ faces ($6$ on each small face) once the large cube is disassembled. Hence the probability is $6n^2/6n^3 = 1/n$.